# Delphi rewriting .dat file

Tags: arrays, file, delphi, url-rewriting

I'm using Delphi and am attempting to rewrite a .dat file which stores records of books. One of the variables is .BookAmountAvailable, when a book is taken out I want it to lower to .BookAmountAvailable of that record by 1, I've read the file into a typed array, then found the correct book and lowered the amount available by 1.

When I rewrite the file with the updated array it doesn't write it correctly (it only writes one of the records back correctly, and the rest of the records are left blank.

The code to read into the array is:

```
assignfile (BookFile,'BookFile.dat');
reset (BookFile);
BookCounter := FileSize(BookFile);
SetLength(BookArray, BookCounter);
for Count1 := 1 to BookCounter  do
  begin
    read(BookFile, SingleBook);
    BookArray[Count1] := SingleBook;
  end;
closefile (BookFile);
```

The code I've used to rewrite the file is:

```
  BookArray[Count].BookAmountAvailable := BookArray[Count].BookAmountAvailable -1;
  assignfile (BookFile, 'BookFile.dat');
  rewrite (BookFile);
  for Count1 := 1 to BookCounter do
    begin
      seek (BookFile, Count1);
      write(BookFile, BookArray[Count1]);
    end;
  closefile (BookFile);
```

What is it that is causing it to not rewrite the array properly?

Comment: Time to tool up and use a database

Comment: This is for a college project and the exam board insists on not using a database :/

Comment: Do they also insist you use awful legacy Pascal I/O? Too bad.

Comment: Nobody here can conclusively tell you the problem in *your* program. Even if someone could, the answer would be useless to anyone else on the Internet since nobody else who had your problem could search for something and arrive here for the answer. You need to use your **debugger** to investigate the problem. Try it with smaller cases until you isolate the problem. You can also try taking your program to your instructor and asking him or her for assistance.

Comment: Why are you seeking? The file pointer advances when you write.

Comment: What is the type of BookArray?

Comment: Based on how it's used, @Robert, it's a dynamic array of records.

Comment: @RobKennedy, but the size of the record structure in that array is in question, since FileSize(BookFile) is used to set the array size.  It indicates it could be a single byte, which seems suspect.

Comment: @Robert, [`FileSize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.FileSize) returns the size of the file in *records*, not in bytes.

Comment: To work correctly as shown, and IIRC,  BookFile should be declared as File of SingleBook.

Comment: `file of <typeof(SingleBook)>`, @Despatcher, since `SingleBook` is a variable. If the code in the question compiles, then we don't need to guess that that's how it's declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

- Dynamic Arrays are ZERO based, and your indexing them as 1 based arrays.
- Seek() call is not needed.

Comment: Tried this the other day and now it works perfectly, thanks for pointing out my mistakes!